# twitter bootstrap wizard: multiple events handling does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

I am using [twitterbootstrap wizard](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/). I have implemented [onTabShow](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-finishbutton.html) event and [onNext](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/validation.html) event of the wizard according to the examples in the site. Even though OnNext event is fired properly but onTabShow does not fire. Is there any constraint in twitter-bootstrap-wizard i.e. only one wizard event onTabShow(Change/Click) event can be implemented simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what's the problem is.Previously I did the following thing:

```
var onWizardTabShow=function(tab, navigation, index) {      
    ....
};
var onWizardTabNext=function(tab, navigation, index) {      
    ....
};
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
         onTabShow:onWizardTabShow
});
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
         onNext:onWizardTabNext
});
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
          onTabClick:(tab, navigation, index) {     
    ....
         }
});
```

Now, instead of binding the events in separate statements, I bind them in one statement.In previous case, only the 1st event binds successfully.

```
var onWizardTabShow=function(tab, navigation, index) {      
    ....
};
var onWizardTabNext=function(tab, navigation, index) {      
    ....
};
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
         onTabShow:onWizardTabShow,
         onNext:onWizardTabNext,
         onTabClick:(tab, navigation, index) {      
    ....
         } 
});
```